# Возможно ли схлопнуть бордер?

Tags: вёрстка, border

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum.</div>
</div>
```

```
.list {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  color: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://jsfiddle.net/9qz43v0g/13/

Answer (score 0):

Легко

```
.list {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-collapse: true;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.item {
  color: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/12m40xuq/

Comment: Лучше всего переносить код в строенный сниппет, который открывается при комбинации `Ctrl+M`

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `box-shadow` + `margin` в одно из двух осей (допустим bottom и right)

```css
.list {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  color: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  /* ----- */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
  margin: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum.</div>
</div>
```